# I'm getting an error of 'ModifiedTensorBoard' object has no attribute '_write_logs' while running this code to train a Deep Q Network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm running the following code:

```
class ModifiedTensorBoard(TensorBoard):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.step = 1
        self.writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(self.log_dir)

    def set_model(self, model):
        pass

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.update_stats(**logs)

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        pass

    def on_train_end(self, _):
        pass

    def update_stats(self, **stats):
        self._write_logs(stats, self.step)
```

The error is obtained:

```
    232     def update_stats(self, **stats):
--> 233         self._write_logs(stats, self.step)
    234 
    235 

AttributeError: 'ModifiedTensorBoard' object has no attribute '_write_logs'
```

Can someone suggest how to overcome this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have to write your one version of `_write_logs`. Here is the [link](https://github.com/Sentdex/Carla-RL/blob/master/sources/tensorboard.py) hope it helps.

Comment: thanks! was able to solved this issue

Comment: @HRISHAV RAJ, Can you post the solution so that it will benefit the community. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors was able to resolve this issue but got another error while trying this. And got another while fixing that. Wasn't able to completely resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

create a "_write_logs" function as following:

```
def update_stats(self, **stats):
    self._write_logs(stats, self.step)

def _write_logs(self, logs, index):
    with self.writer.as_default():
        for name, value in logs.items():
            tf.summary.scalar(name, value, step=index)
            self.step += 1
            self.writer.flush()
```